# How to verify if keyboard input was given

Tags: java, eclipse

At the risk of sounding really dumb, here i go:

Can someone tell me how to verify if a string was entered through the scanner?

I've written some code down below but i'm stuck. 
As you'll probably notice, I'm a complete novice.

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);
        char reply;

        do {
            System.out.print("Nieuwe klant? (j/n)");
            reply = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        } while (reply != 'j' && reply != 'n');

        String giveFirstName;
        String giveLastName;
        String giveStreet;
        String giveNumber;
        String giveCity;
        String giveLand;
        String giveMail;
        String giveGsm;
        String enterLastName;
        String enterFirstName;

        if (reply == 'j') {

            System.out.print("Voornaam Klant:  ");
            giveFirstName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Achternaam Klant:  ");
            giveLastName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Straatnaam:  ");
            giveStreet = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("nummer:  ");
            giveNumber = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Stad:  ");
            giveCity = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Land:  ");
            giveLand = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("E-mail adress:  ");
            giveMail = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Gsm-nummer:  ");
            giveGsm = keyboard.next();


        } else {
            out.print("Voornaam bestaande klant:");
            enterFirstName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Achternaam bestaande klant:");
            enterLastName = keyboard.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "verify if a `String` was entered"? The scanner won't return anything as long as the user doesn't input anything, if that's what you mean.

Comment: The validation is the code actually continuing to do something, as `Scanner#next()` does wait for an enter (but it wont if there is more than 1 value provided which it identifies by the next Token, as a whitespace in this case `Input1 Input2`).

Comment: well paul, it's my intention to check if the user has given input before i continue the program

Comment: Yeah @Paul, is right. The user cannot skip without entering something through the scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well going by this...
*"Can someone tell me how to verify if a string was entered true the scanner ?"*
and your comment...
*"it's my intention to check if the user has given input before i continue the program"*

If you simply want to check if the user has provided an input then you don't need to do anything. This is becasue the Scanner.next() method is a blocking method.

From the APi docs...
*"This method may block while waiting for input to scan."*

What is a blocking method?
Blocking methods in Java are those methods which stop the executing thread until their operation finished.

So the .next() method handles this input verification for you by stopping the rest of your code from running (blocking) until the user has entered an input.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/what-is-blocking-methods-in-java-and.html#ixzz4TZjxJ8Ri

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
do {
    System.out.print("Nieuwe klant? (j/n)");
    reply = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
} while (reply != 'j' && reply != 'n');
```

While I'm not sure what `.findWithinHorizon(".",0)` is, here is another way to read a char.
Changing your do while loop from this

```
do {
    System.out.print("Nieuwe klant? (j/n)");
    reply = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
} while (reply != 'j' && reply != 'n');
```

to this

```
do {
    String input;
    System.out.print("Nieuwe klant? (j/n)");
    input = keyboard.next(); //Gets next String
    reply=input.charAt(0); //Sets String input to char reply
} while (reply != 'j' && reply != 'n');
```

Will read a char. I hope this helps!